# Network caching REST API requests in JIO network

Tags: android, android-volley

In my android app, I am using android Volley for network requests without any caching mechanisms, But I encountered strange problem with JIO network. With JIO network, API requests are cached, and next time its returning same response and request is not directing to server. And if i delete APN type(xcap) from APN settings in Device, requests are not caching. Has anyone encountered same problem ? Kindly help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing issue on only JIO network which is strange.

But still i suggest you to disable cache and try, If still the problem persist then need to find some other way.

To disable the cache you can try:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    queue.getCache().clear();
    StringRequest myReq /*...*/
    myReq.setShouldCache(false);
    queue.add(myReq);
```

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav .. I have tried, but its not working. Caching only happening for GET requests. not for other requests..

Comment: and only for JIO ?